# Segmentation fault when calling printf from 32bit assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

```
.intel_syntax noprefix

.data
str: .asciz "test??\n"

.text
    .global main

main:
    push str
    call printf

    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80
```

I build it with `gcc -m32 prog.s -o prog`, and it just produces a segmentation fault when I run it.

When I run `gdb prog`, it says that the error came from `strchrnul`.

Comment: You need to use `push offset str`. PS: do not use the exit syscall directly. Just return from `main` or `call exit` to let the c library clean up properly.

Comment: @Jester I have never seen that in any of the pages I've found. That worked like magic :O. Can you explain why that worked?

Comment: Oh I figured it out. `push offset` will put the address on the stack instead of the first character. I always thought that was `push [str]`?

Comment: Every assembler has its own syntax unfortunately. There is no single "intel syntax" even if people sometimes think so. In `gas` and `masm` for example, you need to use `offset`, in `nasm` you need to use the brackets.

Comment: Jester, copy your comment into an answer, so that Alex can close the question